# difference between declaring and array inside or outise a forloop in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to create a 2D array, but i don't know it's size when i declare it. when i try to add some value in it outside a loop there is no problem, no matters how much values i add.
But when i'm trying to do the same inside a for loop, i don't get the same result, i got some empty spaces in my array.
I do'nt get the difference between what i'm doing inside and outside the loop

```
    let Vs = []
 
let Ts = []
Ts[0] = []
Ts[0][0] = ' test'
Ts[0][1] = ' test1' 
Ts[1] = []
Ts[1][0] = ' test2'
Ts[1][1] = ' test3' 
Ts[2] = []
Ts[2][0] = ' test4'
Ts[2][1] = ' test5' 
console.error('TS : ' + Ts)

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const V = i;
    Vs[i] = []

    Vs[i][i] = V

    let y = i + 1
    Vs[i][y] = V
    console.error(Vs)
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by adding values ? As in extending the size of the matrix ?

Comment: Outside the loop you always assign `[i]`, `[i][0]` and `[i][1]`. Inside the loop you assign `[i]`, `[i][i]` and `[i][i+1]`. (Voting to close as this simple counting issue is on the level of a typo).

Comment: That's it ! Thanks so much ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got a little lost in your assignments within the loop. Maybe the following is more what you are looking for?

```js
let Vs = [], pre='test';
let Ts = [];
Ts[0] = []
Ts[0][0] = ' test'
Ts[0][1] = ' test1' 
Ts[1] = []
Ts[1][0] = ' test2'
Ts[1][1] = ' test3' 
Ts[2] = []
Ts[2][0] = ' test4'
Ts[2][1] = ' test5' 
console.log('TS:', Ts)

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const V = 2*i;
    Vs[i] = []
    Vs[i][0] = pre+V
    Vs[i][1] = pre+(V+1)
}
console.log(Vs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reviewing your code, here's why your getting empty spaces,

In the code block

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const V = i;
    Vs[i] = []

    Vs[i][i] = V

    let y = i + 1
    Vs[i][y] = V
    console.error(Vs)
}
```

You're doing the following :

`Vs[i] = []` creates a new line in your matrix,

And then you insert a value V at column i of that new line, which means you're going to get empty spaces depending on the value of i, if i isn't 0, the first indexes of that row will be empty !

What you then do is insert a value one position later at Vs[i][y], but at the next iteration you're moving on to a new line and incrementing i, leaving you with more empty spaces at evey row...